# Postgres initial replication taking long time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-replication

My Master postgres db is currently < 100 mb.

[image]

I am doing the initial replication on another machine, using command

> pg_basebackup -h 'masters_ip' -D /1TBdisk/postgres/ -U replica -v -P

But its going very slow, and appears to be downloading a huge tablespace (100172766 kb ~= 95 GB ).

Not sure what's going on there. It will eventually complete overnight, but I'd really like to know why the tablespace is close to 95 gb.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had setup archival previously on the master, and the archive directory is taking all that space on master.

```
$ du -s -m *
100033  archive
2954    base
```

I have to find a way to clean the archival